# "Want to relieve from" vs. "want relief from"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, intransitive-verbs

> - Want to relieve from academic pressure.
> - Want relief from academic pressure.

I think the former one is more proper but my teacher said the latter one is correct.

Comment: Have you visited [ell.se] yet? You're welcome to stay active here, of course, but it seems like some of your questions would be a better fit over in that community.

Comment: did not know that I thought we can ask anything here , seems I was wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Relieve* means to give the *relief*. You can't "relieve from academic pressure" though someone could "relieve you from academic pressure". Using the passive, you could "be relieved from academic pressure".

So, to use the verb and noun in full sentences each:

> I want to be relieved from academic pressure.
>
> I want relief from academic pressure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the latter ( Want relief from academic pressure) is correct . I am assuming the context is you want to be relieved . In this case , You either want relief or want to be relieved , but not want to relieve. That is - The former one doesn't have an object either explicitly or implicitly.

I think the first one can be made proper by changing it to 'Want to be relieved from academic pressure'  Or you can change it to 'Want to relieve (object) from academic pressure' , which changes the context.

Comment: 'Relief' and 'relieve' are used quite differently and it is essential to read the rules to get them right. Especially be careful with 'relieve', as 'relieving yourself' means urinating! You run the risk of causing many a smile if you use 'relieve' incorrectly.

Comment: @WS2 though only without a stated object. "I relieved myself from duty" would not be taken as meaning I urinated.

Comment: 'The guards are relieved on the hour' ??